# AutoComplete in AjaxToolKit

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I want to use `AjaxToolKit` `AutoComplete` feature.
The syntax for the tag is:

```
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="autoComplete1" runat="server"
  EnableCaching="true"
  BehaviorID="AutoCompleteEx"
  MinimumPrefixLength="2"
  TargetControlID="myTextBox"
  ServicePath="AutoComplete.asmx"
  ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" 
  CompletionInterval="1000"  
  CompletionSetCount="20"
  CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement"
  CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem"
  CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem"
  DelimiterCharacters=";, :"
  ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
  <!-- Some formatting code -->
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

There are attribute ServicePath and ServiceMethod which helps tag to fetch data from.
The ServiceMethod has schema:

```
[WebMethod]
public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
```

The method expects only two parameters.
For some business logic requirement I want to send three parameters to method as:

```
[WebMethod]
public string[] GetCompletionList(string type, string prefixText, int count)
```

How can I pass this third parameter and accept it in service method for processing.
My results will be dependent on this type parameter.
How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a contextKey through as a third argument.

When setting up the ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender, add the key-value pair UseContextKey="True", eg

```
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="autoComplete1" runat="server"
  UseContextKey="True"
  EnableCaching="true"
  BehaviorID="AutoCompleteEx"
  MinimumPrefixLength="2"
  TargetControlID="myTextBox"
  ServicePath="AutoComplete.asmx"
  ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" 
  CompletionInterval="1000"  
  CompletionSetCount="20"
  CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement"
  CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem"
  CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem"
  DelimiterCharacters=";, :"
  ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
  <!-- Some formatting code -->
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Set the context to whatever string you want before the service method is called:

```
function setContextKey() {
    text = 'my type information';
    $find('<%=autoComplete1.ClientID%>').set_contextKey(text);
}
```

Then in your code behind, you have access to that contextKey:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
{
    string myType = contextKey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a third parameter. But you can may be read this parameter info by storing and then retrieving it from `Session` or `Request`, by accessing them from the `HttpContext.Current`, since you are in a static method.

Comment: Are you sure?  In my case I have four radio buttons and I want to consider which one is checked while returning list. I dont want to make any postback during this whole process. How can we identify which radio button is checked.

Comment: Add a breakpoint in the `GetCompletionList` method and watch the `HttpContext.Current.Request` you will see all the form inputs. This works like this, because when the method is invoked, the browser performs a Request to the server and sends all the form data. There will be the radiobuttons values